# How to implement multi-threading and parallel execute several tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am new to threaded programming. I have to run few tasks in PARALLEL and in Background (so that main UI execution thread remain responsive to user actions) and wait for each one of them to complete before proceeding further execution.

Something like:

```
foreach(MyTask t in myTasks)
{
  t.DoSomethinginBackground(); // There could be n number of task, to save 
                               // processing time I wish to run each of them 
                               // in parallel
}

// Wait till all tasks complete doing something parallel in background


Console.Write("All tasks Completed. Now we can do further processing");
```

I understand that there could be several ways to achieve this. But I am looking for the best solution to implement in .Net 4.0 (C#).

Comment: How you implement MyTask?

Comment: Well, MyTask could be anything. It doesn't matter here. In my actual solution I have Array of URL and I have to fetch the HTML(Web Scrapping) for each one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me it would seem like you want [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)

```
Parallel.ForEach(myTasks, t => t.DoSomethingInBackground());

Console.Write("All tasks Completed. Now we can do further processing");
```

You can also perform multiple tasks within a single loop

```
List<string> results = new List<string>(myTasks.Count);
Parallel.ForEach(myTasks, t =>
{
    string result = t.DoSomethingInBackground();
    lock (results)
    { // lock the list to avoid race conditions
        results.Add(result);
    }
});
```

In order for the main UI thread to remain responsive, you will want to use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and subscribe to its [`DoWork`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) and [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) events and then call

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
worker.RunWorkerAsync(argument); // argument is an object
```

Comment: Thanks Nolonar, seems a neat solution so far. But what if each tasks returns a value(say string value) and I have to consolidate return string from each task before proceeding further? In other words, can each task return value on completion while other tasks are still busy?

Comment: Nolonar, the second code block seems a nice solution to me. For running the task in background can I use BackgroundWorker with PLINQ?

Comment: @Aakash I'm not sure what you mean with using a BackgroundWorker with PLINQ. You can use PLINQ *inside* a BackgroundWorker, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. I created a BackGroundWorker Instance and in DoWork() method I used PLINQ to run each task in parallel. Each task returns a Collection of String, which I stored in a global collection of string using AddRange() method.

Comment: Wondering if DoWork could send a value as Argument to RunWorkerCompleted event. Like if I declare a local variable in DoWork and pass that in RunWorkerCompleted ?

Comment: @Aakash You can pass an object to `RunWorkerAsync`, like for instance `worker.RunWorkerAsync(t)`, the argument will be in `DoWorkEventArgs.Argument` as object, so you will have to cast it, like `MyTask t = (MyTask)e.Argument`. You can also use the `DoWorkEventArgs` class to put your result in it, see [BackgroundWorker Examples, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Nolonar and everyone for answering this Question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473%28v=vs.100%29) library to complete:

```
 string[] urls = ...;
 var tasks = urls.Select(url => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(url)));
```

To avoid locking UI Thread, you can use [`ContinueWhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473%28v=vs.100%29) in .NET 4.0:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), _ => 
    Console.Write("All tasks Completed. Now we can do further processing");
);
```

If you are in the latest version of .NET, you can use `Task.WhenAll` instead

Comment: Still I think that the second block of code should be run on other thread than Main.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Net 4.0 or up, refer to the Parallel class and Task class. Joseph Albahari wrote very clear book about that: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Creating_and_Starting_Tasks

Comment: Thanks Huy, surely will do, seems it is time to dive into multi-threading. Sooner or later one have to do it. ;-)